# Help understanding this integration result

Tags: complex-analysis

I am learning Complex Integration and i have come across this result i need some helo understanding.
The book, in a solution, states that

$$=\frac{1}{2\pi a^2}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-(n-1)i\theta}[1+\frac {e^{2i\theta}}{a^2}+\frac {e^{4i\theta}}{a^4}+\cdot \cdot \cdot]d\theta$$

$$=0 \text { if n is even}$$

and if $n$ is odd

$$=\frac{1}{2\pi a^2}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-(n-1)i\theta} \frac {e^{(n-1)i\theta}}{a^{n-1}}d\theta$$

I do not understand these two results. I know that $$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{mi\theta}d\theta=0\forall m\ne0$$

Comment: The latter is for all $m \neq 0$. You have $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{0i\theta}\,d\theta = 2\pi$, of course. Then if $n$ is even, $e^{-(n-1)i\theta}e^{2ki\theta}$ always has the form $e^{(2m+1)i\theta}$, which integrates to $0$. If $n$ is odd, one term has a factor $e^{0i\theta}$.

Comment: oh ! That was so silly of me. Thanks !! Please post it as an answer so that i can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $n$ is even, $n = 2m$, then we have

$$e^{-(n-1)i\theta}\cdot e^{2ki\theta} = e^{(2k-2m+1)i\theta},$$

and $2k-2m+1\neq 0$, so the integral over every term of the sum vanishes. For odd $n$, $n-1$ is even, and there is one term in the sum where the exponential terms multiply to the constant $1$, and the integral over that term does not vanish.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: the series only converges if $|a|\gt1$.

Let $z=e^{i\theta}$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{2\pi a^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-(n-1)i\theta}}{1-\frac1{a^2}e^{2i\theta}}\,\mathrm{d}\theta
&=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-ni\theta}}{a^2-e^{2i\theta}}\,\mathrm{d}e^{i\theta}\\
&=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{z^{-n}}{a^2-z^2}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
\end{align}
$$
where $\gamma$ is a counterclockwise unit circle. Since $|a|\gt1$, the only singularity inside the unit circle is at $z=0$ and
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}\left(\frac{z^{-n}}{a^2-z^2}\right)
&=\frac1{2a^2}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}\left(\frac{z^{-n}}{1-\frac za}+\frac{z^{-n}}{1+\frac za}\right)\\
&=\frac1{2a^2}\left(\frac1{a^{n-1}}+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{a^{n-1}}\right)\\
&=\frac1{a^{n+1}}\frac{1-(-1)^n}2
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac1{2\pi a^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-(n-1)i\theta}}{1-\frac1{a^2}e^{2i\theta}}\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\frac1{a^{n+1}}\frac{1-(-1)^n}2
$$
which agrees with the answer given.